# C socket programming: get IP address (IPv6 or IPv4) server bounds to, and client connected to?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have written code like below. This code should enable to retrieve IP address both for PASSIVE_SOCKET (where server bound its socket), and CONNECTION_SOCKET (where client has connected to).

```
result_t print_socket_address(int sockfd, socket_type_t socket_type) {

    char *ip_address; // address (passive) socket was binded to
    int port; // port (passive) socket was binded to

    switch(socket_type)
    {
        case PASSIVE_SOCKET:
            if(get_current_address_and_port(sockfd, &ip_address, &port) == FAILURE) {
                fprintf(stderr, "get_current_address_and_port: faild!\n");
                free(ip_address);
                return FAILURE;
            }
            printf("Created passive socket %d binded to %s:%d\n", sockfd, ip_address, port);
            break;
        case CONNECTION_SOCKET:
            if(get_peer_address_and_port(sockfd, &ip_address, &port) == FAILURE) {
                fprintf(stderr, "get_peer_address_and_port: faild!\n");
                free(ip_address);
                return FAILURE;
            }
            printf("Socket %d connected to %s:%d\n", sockfd, ip_address, port);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect socket type!\n");
            free(ip_address);
            return FAILURE;
    }

    free(ip_address);
    return SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * function retrieves current ip address and port
 * socket is bound to for given socket file descriptor
 */
result_t get_current_address_and_port(int sockfd, char **ip_address, int *port) {

    struct sockaddr sockaddr;
    socklen_t sockaddrlen = sizeof(sockaddr);

    if(getsockname(sockfd, &sockaddr, &sockaddrlen) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getsockname: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    sockaddr.sa_family = AF_INET6;

    return get_address_and_port_from_sockaddr(&sockaddr, ip_address, port);
}

/**
 * function retrieves peer ip address and port
 * socket is connected to for given socket file descriptor
 */
result_t get_peer_address_and_port(int sockfd, char **ip_address, int *port) {

    struct sockaddr sockaddr;
    socklen_t sockaddrlen = sizeof(sockaddr);

    if(getpeername(sockfd, &sockaddr, &sockaddrlen) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getpeername: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    return get_address_and_port_from_sockaddr(&sockaddr, ip_address, port);
}

/**
 * function unwrap ip address and port from addrinfo structure
 */
result_t get_address_and_port_from_addrinfo(const struct addrinfo *addrinfo, char **ip_address, int *port) {

    return get_address_and_port_from_sockaddr((struct sockaddr *)addrinfo->ai_addr, ip_address, port);
}

/**
 * function unwrap ip address and port from sockaddr structure
 */
result_t get_address_and_port_from_sockaddr(const struct sockaddr *sockaddr, char **ip_address, int *port) {

    *ip_address = (char *) malloc(INET6_ADDRSTRLEN * sizeof(char));

    // converting network address to presentation address
    if(inet_ntop(sockaddr->sa_family, get_in_addr(sockaddr), *ip_address, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN * sizeof(char)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "inet_ntop: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    // converting network port to host port
    *port = ntohs(get_in_port(sockaddr));

    return SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * function unwrap in_addr or in6_addr structure from
 * sockaddr structure depending on address family
 * AF_INET or AF_INET6
 */
void *get_in_addr(const struct sockaddr *sa) {

    if( sa->sa_family == AF_INET) // IPv4 address
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    // else IPv6 address
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

/**
 * function unwrap in_port from sockaddr structure
 * depending on address family AF_INET or AF_INET6
 */
in_port_t get_in_port(const struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if( sa->sa_family == AF_INET ) // IPv4 address
        return (((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_port);
    // else IPv6 address
    return (((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_port);
}
```

But when I use this code I get some odd behaviour. Returned IP address where my server bounds socket is for example:

> Created passive socket 4 binded to ::ba54:431c:f9:55401

55401 is the port number and it is correct. But what is this ::ba54:431c:f9? I think maybe this is some IPv6. But why? My Computer in local area network has IP address 192.168.8.102! 
More over when I try to connect with this server by the client program then I must use 192.168.8.102 IP address to get connected otherwise using this ::ba54:431c:f9 I get error like "No route found"? When the client connects using 192.168.8.102 IP address with the server and then it prints IP addres and port number of computer it connected to I am getting another ODD IP Address like this:

> Socket 3 connected to ::3300:5208:6d16:9c88:55401

So here only port number matches and the IP address is not correct! 
More over Client socket while binding locally before connecting with server has bound IP address the same as IP address of computer it is connecting to (it is physically different computer in my LAN network), i.e. ::3300:5208:6d16:9c88:52040, where 52040 is port where client bound its socket.

I have even tried to convert IP address of server computer 192.168.8.1 to IPv6 but I am getting something like this: 0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:866 and this address when used in client program to connect to server works correctly! But Client using above functions print this totally different IP address like: ::3300:5208:6d16:9c88:52040

So how should I write this function to:

1. enable server print IP address and port number it is bounded (in general IPv6 or IPv4 can connect to any address/any port it chooses)
2. enable client to print IP address and port number it is bounded to and it is connecting to (in general can be using IPv4 or IPv6 depending on the needs).

I would like to display in server program IP address and port number which then I could use in client program to connect both. Now I need to guess that it should be my computer address found in Network Preferences and assume port number is correct and then try to connect.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with this code: `sockaddr.sa_family = AF_INET6;` ? Looks for me like you change the family of the address you got to IPv6 which might explain the unexpected IPv6 addresses you get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from `get_current_address_and_port`.

```
    sockaddr.sa_family = AF_INET6;
```

I don't know how that line got written into your code, but it's incorrect.

By removing that line, that will clear up most of your issues for IPv4.

Your code is hardwired to use a `struct sockaddr`.  IIRC, sockaddr isn't big enough for IPv6 addresses anyway.  May I suggest converting it to a `sockaddr_storage` for the initial call to `getsockname` and `getpeername` so your code can work better for both IPv4 and IPv6.

Example fixup:

```
result_t get_current_address_and_port(int sockfd, char **ip_address, int *port) {

    struct sockaddr_storage address = {0};
    socklen_t sockaddrlen = sizeof(address);

    if(getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)(&address), &sockaddrlen) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getsockname: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    return get_address_and_port_from_sockaddr((struct sockaddr*)(&address), ip_address, port);
}


result_t get_peer_address_and_port(int sockfd, char **ip_address, int *port) {
    struct sockaddr_storage address = {0};
    socklen_t sockaddrlen = sizeof(address);

    if(getpeername(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)(&address), &sockaddrlen) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getpeername: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return FAILURE;
    }

    return get_address_and_port_from_sockaddr((struct sockaddr*)(&address), ip_address, port);
}
```

Comment: This line ` sockaddr.sa_family = AF_INET6;` was only added for testing, and I remember to delete it before posting in this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Now I am getting such message: "Created passive socket 4 binded to :::55494"

Comment: That is correct for IPv6. Your local socket is binded to INADDR_ANY (0),   which means "listening on all adapters".  As a string, this translates to `::` as an IPv6 address.  You didn't show how your socket is getting created or binded, but presumably you created an IPv6 socket or kept the hardcoded `AF_INET6` flag in your code path.

Comment: If it was an IPv4 socket, it would have gotten printed as "0.0.0.0".  Which would also be technically correct.

Comment: On client side it prints correct IP addresses now. "socket 3 binded to 192.168.8.100:52622", and "Socket connected to 192.168.102:55536". On server side also when connected with client there is info like this "Socket 5 connected to ::ffff:192.168.8.100:52622". So now it seems ok. As you have said this "Created passive socket 4 binded to :::55536" seems to be correct and this is something like INADDR_ANY. But how can I print address that will inform the client how it can connect with server (i.e. real IP address of server computer).

Comment: Server passive socket is defined like this: 
addrinfo_hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // current host IP
    addrinfo_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET to force IPv4, AF_INET6 to force IPv6
    addrinfo_hints.ai_socktype = (int) sock_type;

Comment: By passing AF_UNSPEC, you are letting the system pick IPv6 instead of IPv4 on your behalf.  By default, IPv6 listen sockets can accept IPv4 connections. That's why those addresses are prefixed with `:ffff`.

Comment: If you want to get your actual local IP address before a client connects to it, then take a look at the helper functions I have here for enumerating local addresses. https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/networkutils/adapters.cpp

Comment: Ok IPv6 isn't the problem. But I would like the server instead of printing: "binded to :::55594" to print "::ffff:192.168.8.102:55594" or just "192.168.8.102:55594"

Comment: If you want to get the local IP address of your device before a client connects to it, call [getifaddrs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getifaddrs)

Comment: Ok I look at this